# Remove pagination number after search query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I want to remove pagination number in Bootstrap pagination, after some search queries. 
Working example is here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pedjamarkovic/8cBpC/71/)

```
var $rows = $('#employeesTable.table tr.tableBody');
$('#employeeSearchBox').bind('keydown keypress keyup change', function () {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function () {
        var firstName = $(this).find('.employeesFirstName').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var lastName = $(this).find('.employeesLastName').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var firstAndLastName = firstName.concat(" "+lastName);
        var lastAndFirstName = lastName.concat(" "+firstName);
        return !~lastName.indexOf(val) & !~firstName.indexOf(val) & !~firstAndLastName.indexOf(val) & !~lastAndFirstName.indexOf(val); 
    }).hide();    
    $table.find("tbody tr[style='display: table-row;']").hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
});
```

I made search query to use first name and last name for filtering. My table is showing only 5 rows for first page in table, but when I am deleting query text in search field its showing all rows in table and pagination stays the same. I want to fix this, but I am stuck with this code.

Someone has some idea how to solve this? I dont want to use dataTable.js for this.

**EDIT:**
I can add something like this and its going to work also.
Example is here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pedjamarkovic/8cBpC/113/)

Comment: i hope you can use bootstrap data table like this demo http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/6b74w/302/

Comment: Yes, I can use that. But my project is in bootstrap 3, and that is in bootstrap 2. Thanks for sharing! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger a click on the `active page` after the filteration will do the trick,

```
$('#employeeSearchBox').bind('keydown keypress keyup change', function () {

    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function () {
        var firstName = $(this).find('.employeesFirstName').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var lastName = $(this).find('.employeesLastName').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var firstAndLastName = firstName.concat(" " + lastName);
        var lastAndFirstName = lastName.concat(" " + firstName);
        $(".active").click(); < -----here
        return !~lastName.indexOf(val) & !~firstName.indexOf(val) & !~firstAndLastName.indexOf(val) & !~lastAndFirstName.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8cBpC/89/)

Comment: @Rohith sorry about that fiddle. Check it now.